# ADO CursorType ADOpenDynamic works differently in oracle client 12.1 and 12.2

Tags: oracle, delphi, ado

I just upgraded my oracle client from 12.1 to 12.2 and I've noticed that ADO CursorType adOpenDynamics works differently in version 12.1 and 12.2. Namely, for 12.1 move to the next record, which is the last one in the record set, causes that the EOF is set to true. But in 12.2, for the same action, EOF is set to false.  Why do I see this difference? Nothing else was changed, I only upgraded the client from 12.1 to 12.2.

I'm using Delphi XE3, and here is a part of my code where I set up the CursorType:

```
  ADOQuery.CursorLocation := clUseServer;
  ADOQuery.CursorType := ctDynamic;
  ADOQuery.CacheSize := 500;
```